# 6 years with Flickering Screen on a laptop

Tags: display, lenovo-laptop, lcd

I have bought this laptop in 2009. I do not remember exactly when the problem started but it must have been after 4 - 5 years of purchase. Looking for a solution online, I was recommended to replace the LCD cable. However, it did not solve my problem back then.

I did update drivers and used several other OSs with this laptop including Linux and flickering was and still is an issue on all of those Os's. It would be reasonable to think that it's a GPU issue, but there is no flickering on the external display when plugged in!

Sometimes, I do not encounter this problem for months and sometimes my eyes suffer from it for weeks. I would like to hear from people who face this issue with this machine and know if they had found any solution to it.

Additional Notes;

- It has onboard Intel Graphics apparently without PSR.
- Flickering happens even when booting up. (Not on Bios)
- It's inverter is located at the bottom of the LCD panel. Maybe have to replace that?

[Here is the footage](https://vimeo.com/440394478)

Comment: After viewing your video, I am confident that your issue is not in software/drivers. This looks like a defective or broken display panel or a malfunction on the board that drives the display panel.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the plastic frame of the screen surprisingly stopped the flickering. There is even not a bit of flickering now. I don't know if it is a manufacturing defect. Also would like to mention that the bottom of LCD panel (the metal bazel around the LCD) is hot and I can barely put my finger on it no more than 4 seconds. Maybe it causes the inverter getting hot and malfunction when the plastic frame is mounted. Also there is a magnet glued on that removed plastic frame (!)

Hope this helps others who have the same issue with Lenovo Y430

[LCD without the frame](https://vimeo.com/440913898)